# Punchout catalogue with nodes

Tags: sap-ariba, cxml-commercexml

I need to create an punchout enabled catalogue.

The end result should be following:

1. Customer should be able to see my site as a supplier in Ariba.
2. He visits the supplier website from within Ariba and add items to the shopping cart.
3. Punchout the items back to Ariba and place and order in Ariba.

I am having a hard time figuring out the steps for cXML integration with my site.

Comment: I was also having trouble to integrate SAP ariba with node application as all the documents provided are in java so I implemented it on my self. I have written each and every step inside my blog checkout the link it may help  you https://tusharkale.medium.com/sap-ariba-integration-47951d530da0?source=user_profile---------0----------------------------

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to add functionality to your application to receive a cXML PunchOutSetupRequest XML document and send back a cXML PunchOutOrderMessage to Ariba. See this page for more details: https://punchoutcommerce.com/guides/punchout/cxml-punchout-setup-request/